# PagedListAdapter fetching all the items when recycler view is placed inside nestedscrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components, android-nestedscrollview, android-paging-library

I am using a NestedScrollView and inside that, I am having some edit text and buttons and then a RecyclerView. When I open the activity all the items start fetching from the server using the PageKeyedDataSource and the RecyclerView scrolls very slowly and in the end the app show ANR.

I have looked this issue in the GitHub repo of android-architecture-components and found that SmartNestedScrollView can solve the problem but when I use SmartNestedScrollView then only a small portion of my recycler view scrolls.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/215

**LayoutFile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.magtappofficial.app.utilities.SmartNestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    tools:context=".ui.Home">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="0px"/>


    <EditText.../>

    <ImageView.../>

    <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/newsProgress"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exclusiveForYou"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/newsRecycler"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exclusiveForYou"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.magtappofficial.app.utilities.SmartNestedScrollView>
```

Can Anyone Please tell me what else can I do?

Comment: People just come and downgrade every reasonable question whose answer they don't know, It's fine but it is the main reason some of the important questions have no solution yet.

Comment: Keep it up Guys

Comment: Have you found a fix for this?

Comment: @SaurabhThorat, Well kind of.

Answer (score 0):

***Note: This is not the best practice, it's just a workaround and if someone has any better answer please please please share.***

For those of you who are still looking for an answer, I have a simple fix.

I have just moved the entire view that I wanted to show above the recycler view inside the recycler view, i.e, made that view as the header of Recycler View.

[image: Layout Blueprint]

Inside the Recycler View :

```
const val HEADER = 0
const val REAL_ITEM = 1
```

The getItemViewType method which will return the view type to onCreateViewHolder.

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> HEADER
            else -> REAL_ITEM
        }
    }
```

Inside the onCreateViewHolder method:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): NewsViewHolder {
        val view = when (p1) {
            HEADER -> {
                LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.rv_header, p0, false)
            }
            else -> LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.xyz, p0, false)
        }
        return SomeViewHolder(view)
    }
```

Inside the onBindViewHolder you can get the view type and bind data as per the view requires.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: NewsViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        val viewType = getItemViewType(p1)
}
```

Comment: The correct way of doing this is by using Coordinate Layout.

Comment: Do you have a sample for that?

Comment: No, I would have to create it. @SunnyAgarwal